# How to properly redirect multiple URLs with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's what I have in my htaccess right now:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /themelink/mytheme
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  http://portal.example.com/aff.php?aff=$1&p=mytheme.php [R=301,NC]
```

I have this .htaccess located in the `/themelink/mytheme` directory.

What this does is redirect someone that goes to `http://example.com/themelink/mytheme/123456` to the URL `http://portal.example.com/aff.php?aff=123456&p=mytheme.php`

This is almost what I'm trying to do, but it's not quite where I want it yet.

What I would prefer to do is put the .htaccess in my `themelink` directory and have it recognize whatever folder name came after it in the URL without me having to create an individual folder for each theme.

For example, here's a few sets of links that I would like to work:

`http://example.com/themelink/new-theme/5643434` --->
`http://portal.example.com/aff.php?aff=5643434&p=new-theme.php`

`http://example.com/themelink/bloggertheme/254543` --->
`http://portal.example.com/aff.php?aff=254543&p=bloggertheme.php`

`http://example.com/themelink/test-theme/4353663` --->
`http://portal.example.com/aff.php?aff=4353663&p=test-theme.php`

I can technically do this by just creating a new directory for each theme that I need a redirect setup for and just use the .htaccess above, but I would prefer to have a single .htaccess that will just work with all of them.

Hope this makes sense, please feel free to let me know if any clarifications are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you may move the .htaccess up a level into the `/themelink` directory, and modify it to include two `()` capture groups, the first capturing everything up to the first `/` encountered, and the second capturing everything afterward.

```
# .htaccess in /themelink
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
# Change the RewriteBase (it actually isn't even needed)
RewriteBase /themelink
# $1 is the theme name, $2 is the aff value
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$  http://portal.example.com/aff.php?aff=$2&p=$1.php [R=301,NC]
```

The expression `([^/]+)` matches one or more characters that is *not* a `/` and captures it as `$1`.

Now, I notice that the `aff` value in all your examples is numeric. If that is to be the case, I would recommend making the rewrite a little more specific to match numbers there instead of `(.+)` which matches anything. That way, an invalid URL (something other than numbers) won't redirect, and instead can respond with a 404.

```
# Ensure $2 is an integer with `\d+` (one or more digits)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)$  http://portal.example.com/aff.php?aff=$2&p=$1.php [R=301,NC]
```